# How to alias java.lang.Integer using XStream?

Tags: java, alias, xstream

I'm tweaking an XStream output, and I get the following:

```
      <entry>
        <string>ahh</string>
        <java-class>java.lang.Integer</java-class>
      </entry>
```

So I try to create an alias for java.lang.Integer.class... Doesn't work. I made aliases for many other classes and it works just fine. I also tried to alias `int.class`; no luck.

What's the trick?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I realized this question was not clear enough. What I'm interested in is *not* to alias the element name (XStream does it already very well). I want to alias the data contained in the element. There's nothing like an example:

Here is a test I made:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(Integer.class);
        classes.add(Long.class);
        classes.add(Double.class);
        classes.add(Float.class);

        ArrayList<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
        numbers.add(new Integer(3));
        numbers.add(new Long(3));
        numbers.add(new Double(3));
        numbers.add(new Float(3));

        XStream xml = new XStream();
        xml.alias("inty", Integer.class);
        xml.aliasType("inty", Integer.class);
        xml.aliasPackage("jl", "java.lang");

        System.out.println(xml.toXML(classes));
        System.out.println(xml.toXML(numbers));
    }

}
```

Which outputs:

```
<list>
  <java-class>java.lang.Integer</java-class>
  <java-class>java.lang.Long</java-class>
  <java-class>java.lang.Double</java-class>
  <java-class>java.lang.Float</java-class>
</list>
<list>
  <int>3</int>
  <long>3</long>
  <double>3.0</double>
  <float>3.0</float>
</list>
```

As you can see, element names are well aliased (second list), but if I use it as data, I can't find a way to shorten the class names. I tried most of relevant XStream.alias* methods. What I would like is something like (for the first list):

```
<list>
  <java-class>int</java-class>
  <java-class>long</java-class>
  <java-class>double</java-class>
  <java-class>float</java-class>
</list>
```

Honestly, right now, I doubt this is possible without quite a big hack, but I'm at least sharing the idea.

Answer (score 2):

It is apparently Integer.class

http://code.google.com/p/jpoco/source/browse/trunk/jpoco/src/main/jpoco/internal/xstream/XStreamFactory.java?r=300

```
xstream.alias("totalResults", Integer.class); 
             xstream.alias("startIndex", Integer.class); 
             xstream.alias("itemsPerPage", Integer.class); 
             xstream.alias("age", Integer.class);
```

Comment: If .alias(String, Class) really does what I think it does and what it says it does ( http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#alias(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class) ), isn't this code realiasing pointlessly the same class to many names? And that's exaclty one thing I've tried; I'd be curious to see the output generated by this code.

Comment: I dont know it wasnt my code, I was just using it as an example to potentially answer your question.

Comment: That's what I supposed, thank you anyway! I know XStream had "issues" in earlier releases where you had to alias int.class instead of Integer.class because of (un)boxing and things like that... I guess it might be a little something that is left to fix.

Comment: I think that the call to alias will create an alias for the first variable of type Integer found, then the next alias the next variable of type Integer found etc...